# TypeGraphql graphql upload import cannot be found

Tags: node.js, file-upload, graphql, typegraphql

### Goal

I'm making a project with TypeGraphql and i want to implement user profile picture.

### Problem

When i try to import:

```
import { GraphQLUpload, FileUpload } from "graphql-upload";
```

docker container log returns:

```
src/resolvers/user.resolver.ts(25,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'graphql-upload' or its corresponding type declarations. `
```

### Tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

### What i tried

I tried to install older versions, but that didn't help.

I'll be glad if you could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: i suggest dont do that make just simple rest API for upload image that return imageUrl then sent that into graphql API imageUrl and sent rest of the fields
because is make for query not for uploading but you can do uploading with graph that possible

Answer (score 6):

The latest graphql-upload version 16.0.0 did not work for me with node 16 typescript. However, downgrading to the previous version 15.0.2 worked with the following replacements,

```
import GraphQLUpload from 'graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.js';
import graphqlUploadExpress from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use this instead

```
import { GraphQLUpload } from "graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload";
import { Upload } from "graphql-upload/Upload";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

import it like this :

```
import graphqlUploadExpress from "graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js"
```

and add this line in tsconfig.json file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "allowJs": true,
  "strict": false
}
```

to allow you to import javascript module,
it works for me

Answer (score -1):

learn ESM and CJS.

I added

```
"module": "ESNext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

to my tsconfig.json.

and

```
import graphqlUploadExpress from 'graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.mjs';
```

to my service

and

```
  "type": "module",
```

to my package.json